# encfs encryted encfs6.xml itself

Tags: encfs

I using EncFS, I did the following:

1. I encrypted a folder using `encfs ~/.folder ~/folder`
2. Afterwards, I changed the password with `encfsctl passwd ~/.folder`

Now, I cannot access my files anymore, because the `.encfs6.xml` file got encrypted itself.

Can I do anything about this? I still have the files, know the password and also saved the encrypted `.encfs6.xml` file.

Any chance I can recover the files/decrypt the `.encfs6.xml` file?

Comment: just have to add that I am pretty sure about the file being encrypted, but I cannot prove it - it is just "scrambled" and encfs cannot read it anymore - don't know how this could happened otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
encfs ~/tmp/test_encfs/.folder ~/tmp/test_encfs/folder
fusermount -u ~/tmp/test_encfs/folder
encfsctl passwd ~/tmp/test_encfs/.folder
```

And `~/tmp/test_encfs/.folder/.encfs6.xml` is still not encrypted.
Probably you are doing something wrong.

Comment: yes, I left out the fusermount step, which probably wasn't a good idea. However, to me it's more interesting to know if this can be fixed somehow. Of course, it makes sense to examine how this could happen. What really seems weird to me: why was the file, but not the filename encrypted? All other filenames have been encrypted as well.

Comment: Even if I do not make fusermount step, everything is still fine (ArchLinux, latest encfs version).
Try these steps again to prove that it is really so (not with important files, of course).
And there is a very little opportunity, that unencrypted .encfs6.xml is still on hdd. Try to `grep` your hdd for it, because you need only 3 parameters from this file: encodedKeyData, saltData, kdfIterations.

Comment: I had cryptkeeper running at the same time, because I thought encfs and cryptkeeper belonged together - as I said, I am really new to encfs etc. I am quite sure that the problem is not caused by encfs but by using it not correctly. However, it doesn't help me now... I "grep"ed without success. Is there any chance I can brute force decrypt the file - it is not really important how long it takes and probably it helps that I still have the correct password?

Comment: It is near to impossible. But better ask in their mailing list https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/encfs-users